# Pass Data From One Application to Another through URL Scheme?

Tags: xamarin.ios

i have tried to pass data gave in textfield from one application to another application through Url Scheme

First i have set the url scheme and identifier in the receiver app info.plist.
i have added LsApplicationQueriesScheme in info.list in receiver app

i have put this code in first sender App. namefield is the Textfield i given in this app.

```
partial void clicked(UIButton sender)
    {  string text = namefield.Text;
        var urlToSend = new Uri("soWhat://" + text);
        Console.WriteLine(urlToSend);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(urlToSend);
}
```

and i have put receiver app AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
        var uri = new Uri(url.Host);
        sun = uri.ToString();
        alert.Message = sun;
        Console.WriteLine(sun);
        alert.Show();
        alert.DangerousRelease();
        return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
    }
```

i have to pass data from one app to another app through urlscheme

Comment: I think you should set the url scheme, identifier and LsApplicationQueriesScheme  in the `sender` app info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Step1: first app sender-app.. 
info.plist Add this points 

        <Array>
    LSApplicationQuerieScheme 
        <string>receiverapp</string>
        </Array>

Step 2. add this code in this viewcontroller button action




    partial void btnact(UIButton sender)
        {
            string name = namefield.Text;
            var names = name.ToString();
            var app = UIApplication.SharedApplication;

            var na = "receiverapp://" + (names ?? "");
            var uri = new NSUrl(na);
            var dict = new NSDictionary();
            if (app.CanOpenUrl(uri))
                {
                app.OpenUrl(uri, options: dict, completion: null);
                Console.WriteLine(uri);
            }

Step 3: In receiverapp 
info.plist add url types 
url-scheme = receiverapp
url-identifier = com.receiverapp
Role = Editor

Step 4: in Appdelegate.cs in receiverapp
add this code



     public string message;
         NSNotificationCenter nc = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter;

            public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
            {
                message = url.Host;
                nc.PostNotificationName("AppInput", null);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                return true;
                //return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
            }

Step5: ViewController.cs in receiverapp
add this code


         AppDelegate dele = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
              public override void ViewDidLoad()
               {
                  base.ViewDidLoad();
                 NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("GetData:"), new NSString("AppInput"), null);
            }
    [Export("GetData:")]
            private void GetData(NSNotification notification)
            {
                  label.Text = dele.message;

                Console.WriteLine(label.Text);
            }
```